# A Counter Field in a Table Going Wrong?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have came up with an idea to help me in my database.
So, I have a form for follow up my patients, that have a lot of fields, and  I have no problems with them, except for one field that I named it **VisitCounter** which basically will add +1 to the previous value, i.e with every visit the patient made , it will count +1 to the previous visit number.

and I created a backstage VBA for it like this:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim count As Integer
count = VisitCounter.Value
Me.VisitCounter.Value = count + 1
End Sub
```

But I ran into two problems

First: with updating any record in the form , the **visitcounter** field will update accordingly, which access will consider it as another update and the counter keeps counting and I find my self stuck in an infinite loop .

second: to solve the previous problem, i had to jump to the next patient record by the navigation buttons, but i find that the counter value continued from the previous record .

So i think because of my deficient VBA experience, i made this silly mistake, but i have no idea how to solve it...

EDITED QUISTION PART:

I think I'll add some details, to make it clear.

The follow Up form  connected to the follow up table which set with a primary key **patientID**.

So, whenever the patient visited the clinic, I don't want to create a new record for that, instead I just updated his old record , by editing the other fields, and it's work fine for me. that's means there is no duplicate records for a single patient.
I think by this way I'll have no redundant records for the same patient.

in summary, I need my follow up form when I open it, to tell me what is the visit number through **visitcounter** field. but it's have the two issues as I mention it before.

Comment: Why would you consider retaining history records redundant? Certainly history is helpful in evaluating patient progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not saving history of visits and just updating patient record with current visit info, saving a visit number not calculated from visit records carries risk of the number getting corrupted. There is no data to substantiate the saved count. However, if you really do prefer this approach, updating the count field can be done simply with:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Me.VisitCounter = Nz(Me.VisitCounter, 0) + 1
End Sub
```

If you visit the record again to do a minor edit and this was not due to an actual visit, the count will still increment and therefore the visit count will not be valid. Perhaps this visit number increment should be tied to update of another field such as VisitDate. Only cause increment if visit date is modified. Use **AfterUpdate** event of VisitDate textbox.

```
With Me
If Nz(.VisitDate.OldValue,0) <> Nz(.VisitDate,0) Then .VisitCounter = Nz(.VisitCounter, 0) + 1
End With
```

If you decide to switch to schema saving visit records, options for the visit counter are:

1. don't save this value to table, use RunningSum property of textbox on report to dynamically generate this sequence number in conjunction with report Sorting & Grouping features - no VBA needed
2. lookup last generated sequence number for that patient and increment by 1, using **BeforeUpdate** event - this works fine as long as visit records are not deleted

```
If IsNull(Me.VisitCounter) Then Me.VisitCounter = Nz(DMax("VisitCounter", "Visits", "PatientID=" & Me.PatientID), 0) + 1
```

Comment: actually no one use the database with me. so I really need it to be in the follow up form, it's make so much sense and ease. as I open the form to update the patient data... I know it's a little bit complicate to explain why I need it this way, but this is what I really need. I hope you can help me to do it in the form vba. Otherwise , I have to count it in a paper notebook  

Comment: I already suggested VBA.

Comment: sorry June7, it's not working at all the way I need it to do.  I think it's quite difficult to do it the way I'm expecting.   So, if that's the case, I'm start thinking of maybe I need another table just for counting , and I'll simply post it to my follow up form, or what should I do ?? .. My experience isn't much, a simple solution would be appreciated.. thanks..

Comment: You need to clarify what 'not working at all the way I need' means. What exactly are you expecting? Programmatically generating a sequence identifier is a common topic and I have offered a commonly used solution.

Comment: I edited the question for you , please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much June7 , it's working perfectly, just the way I wanted to be.... But I'm getting worried of what might be your concern of that it might "carries risk of the number getting corrupted" !! I have no idea of what could happen, but till then, I'm happy with the solution :)

Comment: If you visit the record again to do a minor edit and this was not due to an actual visit, the count will still increment and therefore the visit count is not valid.

Comment: Perhaps this visit number increment should be tied to update of another field such as VisitDate. Only cause increment if visit date is modified. Use AfterUpdate event of VisitDate textbox.

Comment: Thank God, I was thinking it is about something on the level of backstage logic... But for the minor edits there is no problem, as I already planned it, with an IF STATMENT and VISIBILITY PROPERTIES and a couple of BUTTONS, I have a lot of things to play around with.  Thank you so much June7 :)